# Does the review comment have any backend heuristic or stats purpose?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, review

I've been picking "no comment" on the Low Quality Posts view, because I haven't yet felt like any of the comments were helpful in context. Is the backend trying to use these canned comments for some kind of heuristic or stats, and am I kneecapping it by refusing to spam canned comments at old posts?

(Maybe the UI is just sending the wrong signals, because it looks like it *really* wants me to pick a specific option—maybe just because it looks so much like the close-vote and flagging pick lists where choosing a radio button is not optional—and that implied necessity is making me feel like there's something computational going on behind it.)

Comment: I don't have access to the source, but it seems likely that, if there is some heuristic that improves the selection process, "No Comment" will have a "neutral" effect, which is to say none at all.  The Devs, are of course, free to slice and dice the data any way they see fit for analysis purposes, after the fact.